# Quais as principais diferenças entre SOAP, REST?

Tags: web-service

- Quais as principais diferenças entre esses tipos de Web Service?
- Em quais casos se aplicam?
- Existe alguma diferença de performance?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

## SOAP

[**SOAP**](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/) é um protocolo de transferência de mensagens em formato XML para uso em ambientes distribuídos. O padrão SOAP funciona como um tipo de framework que permite a interoperabilidade entre diversas plataformas com mensagens personalizadas.

Aplicando este padrão em Web Services, geralmente usa-se o WSDL para descrever a estrutura das mensagens SOAP e as ações possíveis em um *endpoint*.

Uma das maiores vantagens disso é que várias linguagens e ferramentas conseguem ler e gerar mensagens facilmente. Várias linguagens de programação permitem a geração de objetos de domínio, Stubs e Skeletons a partir da definição do WSDL, permitindo a comunicação remota via [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) através de chamadas a métodos remotos, inclusive com argumentos complexos, como se fossem chamadas locais.

O problema desse padrão, é que ele adiciona um *overhead* considerável, tanto por ser em XML quanto por adicionar muitas tags de meta-informação. Além disso, a serialização e desserialização das mensagens pode consumir um tempo considerável.

## REST

REST é outro um protocolo de comunicação, baseado no protocolo de hipermídia HTTP. Porém ele não impõe restrições ao formato da mensagem, apenas no comportamento dos componentes envolvidos.

A maior vantagem do protocolo REST é sua flexibilidade. O desenvolvedor pode optar pelo formato mais adequado para as mensagens do sistema de acordo com sua necessidade específica. Os formatos mais comuns são JSON, XML e texto puro, mas em teoria qualquer formato pode ser usado.

Isso nos leva a outra vantagem: quase sempre Web Services que usam REST são mais "leves" e, portanto, mais rápidos.

O problema com o REST pode surgir justamente por causa de suas vantagens. Como a definição do corpo de dados fica totalmente a cargo do desenvolvedor, os problemas de interoperabilidade são mais comuns.

## SOAP ou REST?

***Aviso: Esta é uma opinião pragmática.***

Em geral, SOAP é uma boa opção para instituições com padrões rígidos e ambientes complexos (várias plataformas e sistemas). Muitas ferramentas corporativas (como [ESB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)) tiram vantagem do padrão e possibilitam filtrarem, enfileiramento, classificação e redirecionamento das mensagens trocadas entre sistemas.

No restante, para uso no dia-a-dia, não vejo motivos concretos para não usar REST e JSON. Praticamente todas as plataformas e linguagens modernas que conheço suportam esses conceitos e a solução final é muito mais simples do que o equivalente em SOAP.

Além disso, integrações com alto volume de requisições são inviáveis em SOAP. REST é capaz de atender volume e complexidade sem dificuldades, exigindo apenas um mínimo de experiência do desenvolvedor para estabelecer e reforçar os padrões adequados.

Comment: O uso dos [métodos padrões HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) (get, post, put e delete...) pode ser considerado uma vantagem em REST?

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Não me parece uma vantagem, está mais para uma característica ou restrição. SOAP também funciona sobre HTTP, embora isso seja encoberto pelas camadas do protocolo.

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Na verdade, pensando melhor, o fato de REST usar só HTTP faz com que ele seja mais simples, leve, eficiente e compatível do que o SOAP, que exige mais camadas de complexidade. Porém, quanto a usar os métodos padrão do HTTP, isso me parece mais uma característica. Seria como afirmar que um carro é melhor que uma moto porque tem 4 rodas.

Comment: Eu sempre tive essa dúvida, porém acho que isso é levemente uma vantagem pois não foi preciso "reinventar a roda" com novas especificações de protocolos, por exemplo. Já é utilizado "pronto" e ainda mantido por uma organização séria.

Comment: @utluiz, sua resposta foi tão boa que foi copiada: http://blog.desenvolvedorsa.com/diferenca-entre-soap-e-rest/

Comment: @Taisbevalle Obrigado pelo aviso. Não tenho problemas com isto, além do que a licença do site permite. Na verdade, é um bom sinal que algo que eu escrevi há tanto tempo esteja tendo tanto impacto. :D

Comment: O que não percebo é: REST não é um protocolo mas SOAP é. Eu entendo que REST é apenas uma abstração e não é um protocolo, até porque quem faz a comunicação entre 2 sistemas no caso é o protocolo HTTP. A questão é, o SOAP tambem utiliza outros protocolos para o transporte de mensagem, então por que é considerado protocolo?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes REST é um protocolo no sentido de que ele define características bem definidas para comunicação entre duas partes, mesmo que não seja uma definição tão estrita quanto SOAP. O que você está confundindo é que existem diferentes protocolos em diferentes níveis dá comunicação. Já estudou "Redes de Computadores"? Lá você aprende, entre outras coisas, que o protocolo IP atua numa camada, o TCP em outra, HTTP em outra. Agora, em cima disso tudo, adicione REST ou SOAP num nível mais alto.

Comment: Entendo, então dizer que REST não é um protocolo em todos os sentidos é uma falsa afirmação, até porque na própria especificação REST é designado por protocolo: https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/REST . Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: O problema da interoperabilidade no REST, poderia ser resolvido com o [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/). Sei que estou a "ressuscitar" uma questão antiga, mas ela é muito útil e ser for o caso, poderia ser completada.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Sim, você pode resolver o problema dá interoperabilidade adotando um padrão para o conteúdo dá comunicação. Embora isto seja importante na prática, na verdade é também importante que não faça parte do padrão REST, POIs é justamente a flexibilidade dele que o faz ser o que é e permite diversas soluções concorrentes, tais como Jsonb é Protobuf, além das que você citou.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Quanto a completar a resposta, pelo formato do site, acho que seria um pouco off-topic. O ideal é criar outra pergunta mais específica. Fique à vontade para fazer isto.

Comment: REST é um protocolo? Não seria um estilo arquitetural?

Answer (score 47):

> XML é um tipo de documento, não é um tipo de WebService, e ele é usado
>   pelo método SOAP para troca de mensagens.

O texto a seguir foi retirado de: http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each

O REST faz uso de um padrão de URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), fazendo uma chamada para um serviço web como em: http://www.minhaempresa.com.br/programa/metodo?Parametros=xx

O REST é simples de entender e pode ser adotado em praticamente qualquer cliente ou servidor com suporte a HTTP/HTTPS. Os desenvolvedores que o utilizam citam, como principais vantagens a facilidade no desenvolvimento, o aproveitamento da infraestrutura web existente e um esforço de aprendizado pequeno.

Por outro lado, o SOAP, avô das interfaces de serviços web, não deixará de ser usado tão cedo. Com o SOAP v 1.2, muitas das deficiências percebidas nessa tecnologia foram corrigidas e aumentou a facilidade de uso. Além disso, a sigla SOAP deixou de representar "**Simple Object Access Protocol**". Na especificação 1.2 da W3C, SOAP é apenas o nome da especificação.

**Utilizar o SOAP 1.2 traz uma carga adicional não encontrada ao usar REST, mas há também vantagens.** Primeiramente o SOAP é baseado em XML, de três formas: o envelope, que define o conteúdo da mensagem e informa como processá-la; um conjunto de regras de codificação para os tipos de dados; e o layout para os procedimentos de chamadas e respostas. Esse "envelope" é enviado por meio de (por exemplo) HTTP/HTTPS. E uma RPC (Remote Procedure Call) é executada, e o envelope retorna com as informações do documento XML formatado.

**Uma das vantagens do SOAP é o uso de um método de transporte "genérico". Enquanto que o REST faz uso de HTTP/HTTPS, o SOAP pode usar qualquer meio de transporte existente para enviar sua requisição, desde SMTP até mesmo JMS (Java Messaging Service). No entanto, uma desvantagem percebida no uso de XML é a sua natureza prolixa e o tempo necessário para analisar o resultado apresentado.**

**Mas uma história não contada é que ambas as tecnologias podem ser misturadas e combinadas. O REST é fácil de entender e extremamente acessível porém faltam padrões, e a tecnologia é considerada apenas uma abordagem arquitetural. Em comparação, o SOAP é um padrão da indústria, com protocolos bem definidos e um conjunto de regras bem estabelecidas.**

Pode-se afirmar, então, que casos onde o REST funciona bem são:

> Situações em que há limitação de recursos e de largura de banda: A
>   estrutura de retorno é em qualquer formato definido pelo desenvolvedor
>   e qualquer navegador pode ser usado. Isso porque a abordagem REST usa
>   o padrão de chamadas GET, PUT, POST e DELETE. O REST também pode usar
>   objetos XMLHttpRequest (a base do velho AJAX) que a maioria dos
>   navegadores modernos suporta.
>
> Operações totalmente sem-estado: se uma operação precisa ser
>   continuada, o REST não será a melhor opção. No entanto, se forem
>   necessárias operações de CRUD stateless (Criar, Ler, Atualizar e
>   Excluir), o REST seria a melhor alternativa.
>
> Situações que exigem cache: se a informação pode ser armazenada em
>   cache, devido à natureza da operação stateless do REST, esse seria um
>   cenário adequado para a tecnologia.

**Essas três situações abrangem muitas soluções. Então por que ainda precisamos considerar o uso do SOAP? Mais uma vez, o SOAP é bastante maduro e bem definido e vem com uma especificação completa. Já a abordagem REST é apenas isso: uma abordagem. Está totalmente aberta.** Por isso ao se encontrar uma das situações abaixo, o SOAP pode ser uma ótima solução:

> Processamento e chamada assíncronos: se o aplicativo precisa de um
>   nível garantido de confiabilidade e segurança para a troca de
>   mensagens, então o SOAP 1.2 oferece padrões adicionais para esse tipo
>   de operação como por exemplo o WSRM (WS-Reliable Messaging).
>
> Contratos formais: se ambos os lados (fornecedor e consumidor) têm que
>   concordar com o formato de intercâmbio de dados, então o SOAP 1.2
>   fornece especificações rígidas para esse tipo de interação.
>
> Operações stateful: para o caso de o aplicativo precisar de informação
>   contextual e gerenciamento de estado com coordenação e segurança, o
>   SOAP 1.2 possui uma especificação adicional em sua estrutura que apoia
>   essa necessidade (segurança, transações, coordenação etc.).
>   Comparativamente, usar o REST exigiria que os desenvolvedores
>   construíssem uma solução personalizada.

Como se vê, cada uma das abordagens tem sua utilidade. Ambas têm problemas nos quesitos de segurança, camadas de transporte etc.; mas ambas podem realizar o trabalho necessário e trazem sua contribuição para o desenvolvimento de aplicações web.

Retirado de: http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each

Answer (score 10):

**Resposta curta**

SOAP é antiquado, complicado e chato. Em algumas linguagens, o suporte a SOAP vai ficando decadente, há bibliotecas que funcionam mas não são tocadas há quase 10 anos.

**REST** (e GraphQL) são mais modernas, mais fáceis de usar, existe abundância em bibliotecas, documentação, exemplos e geralmente usa JSON.

**XML** também já é bastante obsoleto frente a JSON como formato de troca de dados. SOAP é baseado em XML.

A única coisa marginalmente interessante do SOAP é o WSDL, que é um "schema" fornecido por todo servidor SOAP. De certa forma a API SOAP é auto-documentada pelo WSDL, mas não acho que contrabalança o REST, e já existe "JSON schema" se se faz questão de ter schema.

SOAP tem todo um esquema de definir tipos simples e compostos com constraints no próprio WSDL, é o tipo de coisa que parece interessante a priori, mas na prática é uma complicação desnecessária. A simples composição de tipos simples feita pelo JSON é extremamente prática.

Comment: Para os curiosos que vierem aqui, sobre GraphQL vs REST: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226340/64969