# Servidor WebService em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-service

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um servidor WebServicee usando a gem wash_out (https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out).
Neste meu servidor vou fazer inserção, exibição, exclusão e atualização de dados (CRUD).
Provavelmente será uma aplicação Delphi que acessará o WebService e manipulará os dados.
Sou bem leigo nessa questão de WebService e gostaria de algumas dicas: 
O uso dessa gem é indicada para criar esse servidor? 
Existe outra maneira de fazer um WebService?
Para vocês, qual a melhor maneira para criar um servidor WebService?

Dês de já agradeço

Comment: Webservice usando SOAP é tecnologia ultrapassada. Sugiro que vc dê uma pesquisada por apis REST.

Comment: @AlexTakitani SOAP não é ultrapassado. Ele é mais adequado para um contexto com exigências maiores de padronização e interoperabilidade, muito comum em ambientes corporativos que usam um ESB para coordenar múltiplas aplicações e direcionar as mensagens baseando-se no conteúdo. REST é mais leve e flexível.

Comment: Bruno, sugiro a leitura da [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11186/227) em ["Diferenças de tipos de Web Service: (SOAP, REST, XML)"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/227).

Comment: @utluiz vc faria algo novo usando SOAP em vez de REST?