# O que é WSDL (Web Services Description Language)?

Tags: xml, web-service, rest, soap, wsdl

Relacionado com: [Diferenças de tipos de Web Service: SOAP, REST, XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/7261)

- O que é WSDL?
- Qual sua relação com REST e SOAP?
- Onde encontro a documentação do WSDL?

Comment: O artigo da wikipedia fornece uma boa ideia: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language e a documentação pela W3C aqui http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl e a relação com Rest até onde eu sei é nenhuma e com SOAP é o WSDL que define quais serviços SOAP estão publicados e como os utilizar

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**WSDL** é um a descrição em formato XML de um Web Service que utilizará SOAP / RPC como protocolo. É o acrônimo de Web Services Description Language (Linguagem de Descrição de Serviços Web).

RPC – Remote Procedure Calls (em português, chamada de procedimentos remotos) é um modelo que define a forma como são realizadas as chamadas a operações remotas através de web services.

Por meio de um WSDL você informa ao cliente como cada serviço em um end-point deve ser invocado: quais os parâmetros e tipo de dados de cada parâmetro é esperado, e qual o tipo de dado do retorno será enviado como resposta.

Além de descrever cada serviço (que pode ser comparado analogamente à um método a ser executado no programa servidor), também descreve como podem ser encontrados. Seus elementos básicos são:

```
<types>: aqui deverão ser descritos os tipos de dados suportados pelo serviço em questão

<message>: aqui devem ser especificados os padrões de entrada e saída de dados dos web services

<portType>: aqui devem ser descritos os agrupamentos lógicos das operações. São as operações executadas pelo web service

<binding>: aqui devem ser apresentados os protocolos de comunicação que os web services utilizam

<operation>: região que permite a especificação das assinaturas dos métodos disponibilizados

<definitions>: elemento padrão de todos os documentos WSDL. Permite efetuar descrições sobre schemas e namespaces
```

Neste endereço você pode ver um exemplo de um WSDL para um conjunto de serviços de calculadora:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

O trecho abaixo é o ponto onde define-se os serviços:

```
<wsdl:portType name="ICalculator">
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://Example.org/ICalculator/Add" message="tns:ICalculator_Add_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://Example.org/ICalculator/AddResponse" message="tns:ICalculator_Add_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://Example.org/ICalculator/Subtract" message="tns:ICalculator_Subtract_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://Example.org/ICalculator/SubtractResponse" message="tns:ICalculator_Subtract_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
```

O trecho abaixo descreve como cada serviço deve ser chamado:

```
<wsdl:binding name="DefaultBinding_ICalculator" type="tns:ICalculator">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://Example.org/ICalculator/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://Example.org/ICalculator/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
```

O trecho abaixo define a localização do serviço CalculatorService

```
<wsdl:service name="CalculatorService">
        <wsdl:port name="ICalculator" binding="tns:DefaultBinding_ICalculator">
            <soap:address location="http://Example.org/ICalculator" />
        </wsdl:port> 
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Como citado no primeiro parágrafo, WSDL é utilizado diretamente com SOAP, quando um cliente realiza uma chamada de serviço por meio de SOAP, primeiramente ele solicita o WSDL para entender como se dará esta negociação.

REST trabalha sobre o protocolo HTTP puro, portanto não depende do protocolo SOAP para realizar a comunicação, em consequência não necessita usar uma WSDL. Apenas os verbos HTTP são utilizados. Neste caso, para um cliente solicitar serviços REST, ele necessita de antemão conhecer o caminho e interface deles. Siginifica dizer que o desenvolvedor precisará de manual ou guia de programação para usar uma API REST.

A documentação oficial esta no site da W3C:  w3.org/TR/wsdl

Minha dissertação de mestrado utiliza SOAP e WSDL para um framework de Preço de Venda, você pode ler o capítulo 4 para maior detalhamento, e principalmente, ver as referências que usei, lá você encontra bons documentos sobre SOA: http://repositorio.utfpr.edu.br/jspui/bitstream/1/635/1/PG_PPGEP_M_Mazer%20Junior,%20Ademir_2013.pdf

Answer (score 14):

Falando em termos extremamente simples e práticos:

**WSDL** é um XML que descreve um web service. O conteúdo do WSDL descreve os métodos fornecidos pelo web service e como fazemos para acessa-lo.

Uma boa referência: [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)

**SOAP** é um protocolo utilizado para a troca de informações.

Referência completa: [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)

**REST** é um principio que utiliza simplesmente HTTP e XML ou JSON ou Simplesmente Texto. O REST é (teoricamente) mais performático que o SOAP por não utilizar o processo de envelopagem e desenvelopagem das mensagens.

Referência Completa [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Logo, o WSDL é uma interface de acesso a um webservice e o SOAP é o protocolo utilizado para trocar mensagens entre o webservice e aplicação.

Não existe relação nenhuma entre WSDL e REST. São abordagens totalmente diferentes.

Finalmente, a documentação do WSDL pode ser encontrada no [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl).