# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

Estou a tentar implementar um webservice de um software chamado SmarterTrack só que não estou a conseguir... dá-me o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket.
> ```

Já testei diretamente no browser e funciona extremamente bem.

```
Sub Execute()
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.Host = "localhost:9996"
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim soapEnvelopeXml As New XmlDocument()
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<soap:Body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<CreateTicket xmlns=""http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx"">" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<authUserName>admin</authUserName>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<authPassword>teste123</authPassword>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<departmentID>3</departmentID>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<groupId>3</groupId>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<userIdOfAgent>2</userIdOfAgent>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<toAddress>teste@teste.pt</toAddress>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<subject>test</subject>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<body>teste</body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<isHtml>True</isHtml>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<setWaiting>True</setWaiting>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "<sendEmail>True</sendEmail>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "</CreateTicket>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "</soap:Body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
    "</soap:Envelope>")
    Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream)
    End Using
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using rd As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim soapResult As String = rd.ReadToEnd()
            Console.WriteLine(soapResult)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: A mensagem de erro está clara, você está informando o `SOAPAction` errado. Sem o `WSDL` na pergunta, não é possível te ajudar.

Comment: https://portal.smartertools.com/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?WSDL tenho de o indicar no código?

Answer (score 0):

O problema ocorre pois você está informando um valor errado no [Header `SOAPAction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528).

O valor correto a ser informado está contido no [`WSDL`](https://portal.smartertools.com/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?WSDL) que está consumindo, para saber um pouco mais sobre `WSDL`, veja [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29116/o-que-%C3%A9-wsdl-web-services-description-language).

Você está tentando consumir o método `CreateTicket`, para saber qual o `SOAPAction` correto para este método, precisa buscar essa informação no `WSDL`:

```
<wsdl:operation name="CreateTicket">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/Services2/svcTickets.asmx/CreateTicket" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Observe o valor do atributo `soapAction`:

```
http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/Services2/svcTickets.asmx/CreateTicket
```

Em seu código altere o valor que está atribuindo no `SOAPAction`:

de:

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket")
```

para:

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:9996/SmarterTrack/Services2/svcTickets.asmx/CreateTicket")
```

Obs.: Alterei o `SOAPAction` para o domínio que está tentando utilizar: `localhost:9996`.

Comment: Continua a não funcionar, dá o mesmo erro infelizmente... como uso o WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

Altere o header para:

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:9996/Services2/CreateTicket")
```

Você também pode utilizar a importação de referência WEB, que já faz todo o trabalho de mapeamento do serviço que está consumindo, você não teria a necessidade de construir o XML manualmente.

Para fazer isso, clique com o botão direito no projeto: Add > Service Reference > Advanced... > Add Web Reference cole a URL de seu servico .ASMX ou .ASMX?WSDL atribua um nome (Ex.: Consumir) e clique em Add Reference
Depois no seu código você conseguirá chamar o serviço por:

```
Dim Servico As New Consumir.svcTickets
Servico.CreateTicket(parametros)
```