# Quando e onde usar webservice?

Tags: php, android, web-service

Estou com um projeto de app android que é semelhante ao EasyTaxi (não tem nada haver com taxi, mas segue essa lógica de usar mapa para localizar "taxistas" em tempo real, com cadastro de contas e tudo...).
Até ai ok, já sei muito bem Android, mas nunca trabalhei na vida com Webservice, já li bastante sobre SOAP e REST e com PHP, não entendi perfeitamente o funcionamento...

Quando eu sei que tenho que usar webservice?
Porque usar?
Não consigo encaixar o webservice no exemplo que citei, talvez porque eu não estou entendendo muito bem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existem varias explicações na internet, vou tentar responder de forma menos técnica e mostrar quando usar, porque nós aprendemos mais rápido com a necessidade. Então primeiro vou impor modos de precisar de determinados recursos mas que não são os melhores modos de se fazer e pela necessidade acaba precisando de um Web service.

**Web service**

Quando usar? 
Quero criar um site de noticias na internet, meu publico alvo são usuários Android, iOS e website. Minha base de dados precisa ser unica e compartilhada com essas três plataformas.

Inicialmente você pensaria posso fazer o Android comunicar direto com o banco de dados e buscar as informações necessárias, para isso teria que criar funções de busca, inserção, e delete.
Para o iOS também precisaria dessas funções poderia comunicar direto também, e meu website também preciso disso.

Interessante cada plataforma teria o seu jeito de se comunicar com a base de dados.

Por que não fazer isso?

O mais importante, segurança, você não pode comunicar direto assim com um banco de dados, seria um risco desnecessário.

Outro ponto que se leva em consideração, é que se você reparou todos tem funções em comum, todos buscam os mesmos dados, fazem os mesmos tipos de inserções e deletes na base de dados, então por que eu não posso criar um "cara" que esteja do lado do banco de dados, esse cara faz todas as comunicações para você com o banco de dados, o Android o iOS não solicitam a mesma coisa?  então eu só faço uma vez determinada função e disponibilizo em um endereço na internet, exemplo
`www.meuwebservice.com/pegar_todos_os_posts_do_dia.php`. Agora quando o Android e o iOS querer pegar os "posts de noticia" do banco de dados  ele solicita ao Web service um serviço. O Web service apenas disponibiliza os posts, pra ele não importa quem solicitou se é Android, iOS, website, aplicação desktop.

Pra finalizar sobre Web service, nada mais é que um programa que disponibiliza serviços via internet, para diferente plataformas indiferente a linguagem de programação utilizada, ele compartilha recursos entre plataformas diferentes.

**SOAP e REST**

Mas espera ai, a linguagem do Android é em JAVA, do iOS é em Objective-C e o meu website é em Python, e ainda meu Web service está em PHP. Um fala inglês, outro português, e outro chines. Uma mistura de línguas rsrs. Como posso resolver isso? bem, precisamos de uma linguagem intermediaria que todos devem entender. Mas para isso precisamos definir um protocolo(padrão) de comunicação. 
Ai entra os protocolos de comunicação SOAP ou REST. 
**SOAP** o mais antigo, é um protocolo de transferência de mensagens em formato [XML](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). As mensagens que serão trocadas possui um padrão bem rigoroso e preso ao XML.
**REST** é um protocolo mais flexível, você não fica amarrado ao XML, você pode criar mensagens do tipo texto puro, mensagem com formatos [JSON](http://json.org/json-pt.html) ou até mesmo XML.

Então como funciona essa comunicação?
O Android faz uma solicitação de um serviço ao Web service, ele quer todos os posts de noticia do dia, o web service, então recupera os posts do dia, transforma o conjunto de posts em um arquivo XML, e envia para o Android esse arquivo XML, o Android recebe o arquivo XML, ele saber ler o XML, então faz leitura dos dados dentro do XML e converte os dados para manipular na sua linguagem nativa. O iOS também quer o mesmo tipo de dados, solicita ao Web service, o Web service envia o mesmo XML, o iOS também saber ler XML, então ele, decodifica para manipular em sua linguagem nativa. A mesma coisa para um website, ou até mesmo uma aplicação desktop feito em Delphi, todos recebem o mesmo XML, todos sabem ler o XML, e convertem para sua linguagem nativa, e o Web service executa uma unica função para todas as plataformas. 
Lembre que eles, só sabem ler o XML porque existe um padrão quando o XML foi criado, exemplo, dentro do corpo do arquivo XML, deve existir um pedaço que diz respeito ao contexto da comunicação, essa parte deve ficar no inicio do arquivo e se chama cabeçalho, e uma parte do arquivo deve conter os dados que o cliente solicitou, e vai se chama body. Isso vale para o SOAP onde o arquivo tem um padrão rígido ao ser criado.

Mais sobre [Web service](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).
Mais sobre [SOAP e REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11183/diferen%C3%A7as-de-tipos-de-web-service-soap-rest-xml).

Comment: Muito boa resposta, realmente estava faltando isso para que eu possa entender... Uma resposta menos tecnica. Então seguindo o que você falou, não consigo enxergar um cenário no exemplo que citei onde deveria usar webservice, creio que não é necessário ainda

Comment: sim vc precisaria de um web service vc disse que os usuário precisam cadastrar uma conta ao entrar na aplicação, os dados de login então deve ser armazenados em um servidor  com um banco de dados, Você precisa de um webservice para receber os dados das contas e salvar no banco de dados. Ai quando o usuário for fazer o login na aplicação ele solicita ao web service para fazer autenticação

Comment: Mas para login, não é melhor consultar direto do banco?

Comment: A melhor explicação que já encontrei

Comment: Melhor resposta!! Salvando vidas em 2018 rsrs. Obrigado!