# O que é um Web Service?

Tags: web-service, terminologia

Ultimamente ouvi muito a respeito de Web Service.

> **Web service** é uma solução utilizada na integração de sistemas e na comunicação entre aplicações diferentes. Permitem às aplicações enviar e receber dados em formato XML.
>
> **Web service** é uma solução utilizada na integração de sistemas e na comunicação entre aplicações diferentes. Com esta tecnologia é possível que novas aplicações possam interagir com aquelas que já existem e que sistemas desenvolvidos em plataformas diferentes sejam compatíveis. Os Web services são componentes que permitem às aplicações enviar e receber dados em formato XML. Cada aplicação pode ter a sua própria "linguagem", que é traduzida para uma linguagem universal, o formato XML.

Fonte: https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/447/o_que_e_web_service

Eu não consegui visualizar o que seria um Web Service. Mas afinal, o que ele é? Alguém poderia elucidar com alguma aplicação que ele possa ser utilizado, talvez isso melhore no meu entendimento.

Comment: Qual o problema? Então essa pergunta não é válida pra comunidade só porque tem uma pequena explicação na wiki da tag?

Comment: A `wiki` do PHP por exemplo tem bastante informações. Nada que impede que a de web-service seja melhorada também.

Comment: @renan concordo com você, pra quem está iniciando, nem sempre os termos "técnicos" (como os da wiki) são de fácil compreensão... uma explicação "a grosso modo" as vezes ajuda muita gente nova em alguns termos...

Comment: Achei curioso que nenhuma resposta até agora falou em HTTP. As explicações até agora falam mais sobre *application service* do que *web service*. Isto me deixa claro que as pessoas não sabem com clareza o que é o termo.

Comment: Nesse ponto em concordo com vocês. E eu vi que a @Isabela falou de maneira "bem grosseira", o que as vezes ajuda a esclarecer mais. Retirei o -1. Realmente, tem coisas que para quem está iniciando é mais difícil

Comment: Não acho vergonha admitir que me equivoquei :)

Comment: Acho que até eu não sabia, @bigown.

Comment: @bigown Não há requerimento algum que um webservice **tenha** que usar HTTP. A própria [definição do W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice) só comenta que "normalmente são transmitidos via HTTP". É perfeitamente possível definir o conceito de Web Service sendo agnóstico sobre como os dados são transmitidos.

Comment: @Gabe Mas eu não disse isto também. Eu simplifiquei para comentar, eu não dei uma resposta. Mas as respostas atuais deixam aberto para um serviço qualquer que não seja *web service* . O pessoal está falando de algo que é mais próximo de um API do que um *web service*, ainda que também não responda isto. É o que eu falo, o votos nem sempre refletem a qualidade. Nenhuma está errada, mas nenhuma é boa para definir bem o que é.

Comment: @bigown Ah, sim. Mas esse normalmente vai ser o caso quando a pergunta for sobre coisas que são muito mais próximos de um conceito abstrato do que necessariamente algo concreto com uma definição formal. Web Service é o tipo de termo que é usado bem livremente pra descrever uma idéia, não uma ferarmenta ou tecnologia específica.

Comment: Acho que acabei respondendo essa pergunta aqui também lá na sua outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90374/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-web-service-e-application-service

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Este é um caso onde talvez uma imagem valha mil palavras. Para fins de exemplo, vamos utilizar um site como o pt.stackoverflow.com.

Você pode imaginar a estrutura da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> <sup>Uma aplicação web típica, com camadas cliente e servidor. O backend pode ser dividido em várias outras camadas: No exemplo acima, *endpoints* e *API*
>    compõem a camada de serviços web ou *webservices* que, junto com as regras de negócio, formam a aplicação como um todo.</sup>

Seu *browser* (o cliente do serviço) contacta o servidor da aplicação. Boa parte do conteúdo é estática, e pode ser servida via simples serviço HTTP (imagens, arquivos javascript, css e similares.)

Entretanto, funcionalidades como o *upvote* da sua questão precisam interagir com o banco de dados. Estes comportamentos estão descritos nas regras de negócio do site; e os *webservices* existem para permitir que o browser interaja com estas regras.

Descritos desta maneira, ***webservices* servem como uma interface entre o cliente (neste caso um *browser*) e a estrutura interna de uma aplicação (neste caso, as regras de negócio.)**

Um exemplo é o *upvote*: Quando eu votei positivamente na sua questão, o seguinte *endpoint* foi acessado:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/90315/vote/2

Esse *endpoint* pertence a um *webservice* que recebeu a ação. As regras de negócio do site, por sua vez, propagaram a notificação: Vários usuários receberam uma mensagem do tipo 'Ei, mostre agora 7 votos ao invés de 6.'

Essa explicação é simples, e serve para lhe dar um entendimento inicial de como o conceito funciona. Caso deseje se aprofundar mais, aqui vão alguns recursos:

Especificações de mensagem: [SOAP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/), [REST](http://rest.elkstein.org/); [diferenças entre estes tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11183/diferen%C3%A7as-de-tipos-de-web-service-soap-rest-xml).

Especificações de dados: [JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona), [XML](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/programacao/1762-o-que-e-xml-.htm)

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: Então @OnoSendai, o web service seria uma aplicação (escrita em php, por exemplo) que recebe uma requisição do Browser, interpreta o pedido e retorna uma resposta em forma de XML ou JSON por questões de integração com diversos tipos de sistemas?

Comment: @Duds essa é uma descrição bem próxima da realidade - ajustando um pouco eu colocaria da seguinte maneira: 'O webservice seria a parte da aplicação (em php ou outra linguagem) que serve de intermediária entre o cliente HTTP e os outros aspectos da aplicação, que podem incluir outros sistemas integrados.'

Comment: Obrigado @JorgeB. !

Comment: Obrigado @OnoSendai

Comment: @Duds Um webservice pode possuir um ou mais endpoints. Uma boa maneira de entendê-los é o nome pela qual você expõe um método do seu webservice. Assim, imagine que você tem uma URL do tipo `servidor.com/usuários`, que lista todos os usuários da sua base de dados, e `servidor.com/usuários/1`, que lhe retorna o usuário de ID = 1; os dois métodos estão no mesmo WebService, porém em endpoints diferentes.

Comment: @OnoSendai não sabe como um desenho desses me fez falta há uns 2 meses atrás, rs! +1!

Comment: @mauriciocaserta Antes tarde do que nunca? =)

Comment: @OnoSendai antes tarde do que nunca!

Comment: Agora entendi, muito obrigado @OnoSendai!

Comment: @Duds É sempre um prazer ajudar!

Comment: @OnoSendai, fiquei em dúvida na sua imagem sobre o que seria a API abaixo dos end-points. Poderia me clarificar?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Com prazer! Eu adicionei uma explicação à imagem, dê uma olhada e me diga se está clara.

Comment: @OnoSendai desculpa a demora em responder, mas eu vi no dia mesmo e tinha achado clara. Pelo menos lembrei de responder. Muito obrigado =]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sem problema, fico feliz que você tenha gostado!

Answer (score 18):

Meu conceito de Web Service é :

Uma aplicação (chamarei de *API*) que recebe parâmetros e executa instruções, por exemplo, um cadastro. Uma aplicação recebe os parâmetros "**email**" e "**senha**", faz o cadastro em um banco de dados, e retorna uma resposta de sucesso ou falha em *JSON* ou *XML*.

Uma outra aplicação (chamarei de client) deseja cadastrar usuários nessa "*API*", então ela envia parâmetros por *JSON* ou *XML* (nesse caso "**email**" e "**senha**") e obtem a resposta de sucesso ou falha.

Em resumo, meu ponto de vista é que um web service consiste em uma aplicação ser capaz de receber dados de qualquer lugar (desde que no formato que a mesma possa interpretar), processar esses dados e enviar a resposta para o requisitor.

***Um exemplo que estou desenvolvendo:***

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de clientes web, que possui um módulo que chamo de API, onde recebe parâmetros como **$nome**, **$email** e **$senha**, insere-os no banco e devolve a resposta em *JSON*, com sucesso ou falha da inserção.

Um outro módulo web faz as requisições, enviando os parâmetros **$nome**, **$email** e **$senha** á essa api, e obtem as respostas da mesma. Outro módulo, dessa vez um aplicativo Android faz as mesmas requisições, enviando **$nome**, **$email** e **$senha** e recebendo as respostas. A vantagem disso é uma aplicação central, capaz de processar informações e ser consumida por diversas aplicações diferentes.

Answer (score 14):

Seria quem faz o "meio de campo" entre dois sistemas, vou te dar um sistema bem simples pra ver se tu entende.

Você tem um sistema que chamaremos de 01 onde estão as informações.
Você também tem um sistema que chamaremos de 02 onde você quer ter as informações do sistema 01.

Para facilitar esse transporte de informações entre os dois sistemas, é possível desenvolver um terceiro sistema que vai se comunicar com os outros dois, assim sendo o 01 chama o web service e manda pra ele "Quero importar clientes".

O Web services vai pegar os "clientes" e vai mandar pro 02 "Insere esses dados na tabela de clientes".

Seria mais ou menos nesse sentido que ele trabalha.

Comment: O web service seria o "meio de campo"? Ele sempre rodará no lado do servidor, certo @Isabela?

Comment: @Duds Ele será a ponte entre os dois sistemas. Como assim "do lado" do servidor? Não entendi tua pergunta.

Comment: Então @Isabela, "do lado" do servidor eu quis dizer se o web service funcionará sempre no servidor, a aplicação web service foi feita para funcionar em servidores ou nas máquinas dos clientes?

Comment: @Duds em servidores...

Comment: Obrigado @Isabela

Comment: @Duds Por nada.

Answer (score 11):

Uma aplicação web comum, o navegador lança um pedido (requisição) ao servidor, então o servidor (que está esperando requisições) devolve informações (depois de processar ou não) ao navegador. Essas informações são em HTML que o navegador usa para desenhar a página web.

Uma aplicação webservice funciona de forma semelhante, mas não devolve HTML e sim dados apenas. Normalmente esses dados são em formato XML ou JSON mas pode ser qualquer outro formato.

Uma aplicação prática para isso seria uma aplicativo de celular. Não se deseja transferir a página inteira pois isso demoraria e consumiria muito plano de dados sem contar que um navegador tem que "desenhar" a tela ao recebê-la. 
Em uma aplicativo de celular, as telas (interface) já está pronta (é só exibir) e somente os dados são trocados o que economiza o plano de dados e dá mais velocidade pois a quantidade de dados é menor e não tem que "desenhar" a tela toda vez.

Citei o exemplo do aplicativo de celular, mas nada impede que outros tipos de aplicação usem webservice como por exemplo um aplicativo de emissão de nota fiscal eletrônica envia notas e consulta a situação através de webservice da SEFAZ.

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR**: Webservices permitem que duas (ou mais) maquinas se comuniquem via uma rede.

Para uma explicação mais profunda, imagine o seguinte cenário: A sua empresa negocia produtos em dólar, cujo valor flutua diariamente. É extremamente importante que você tenha esses valores atualizados para que você tome decisões que lhe tragam melhores resultados. Você pode contratar um estagiário pra ficar atualizando esses valores manualmente, ou você pode **consumir um serviço** que lhe forneça essa informação automaticamente e com confiabilidade.

Esse serviço é o tal do *webservice*. Você faz uma pergunta (quantos cinco reais que valem um dólar hoje?), e ele lhe responde. Esse processo, a nível de comunicação, se dá por requisições baseadas no **protocolo HTTP**. Existe um *endpoint* em um servidor que está sempre esperando pela pergunta e, se ela for feita da maneira correta, ele responde. Em uma busca rápida no google, encontrei um webservice que ilustra perfeitamente o caso da cotação do dólar (e de praticamente todas as moedas), que pode ser acessado [aqui](http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate).

A pergunta (ou requisição) deve ser feita corretamente, caso contrário o webservice não vai conseguir entender o pedido. No caso da cotação, a pergunta deve conter as duas moedas que você deseja converter, certo? Usando o webservice linkado acima, fiz a seguinte requisição (em termos chulos, entrei nesse site):

> http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=BRL

e a resposta foi um `XML` no formato

```
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">3.9818</double>
```

Ou seja, através de uma requisição **GET** (os parâmetros estão explícitos na URL), eu consegui a informação que eu desejava dentro de um `XML`. Como é que eu sabia quais parâmetros utilizar ou, em outras palavras, qual é o formato correto da pergunta? Neste caso específico, quem forneceu o serviço também forneceu os parâmetros que o mesmo está esperando para que a informação desejada seja alcançada. Experimente fazer a requisição

> http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromStackOverflowCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=BRL

para ver o que acontece.

A requisição **GET** é uma das quatro requisições padroes do **protocolo HTTP**. As outras são **POST**, **PUT** e **DELETE**. Não entrarei em detalhes de como todas elas funcionam, mas você pode ler sobre o protocolo HTTP [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

O `XML` (que é o formato do retorno) é uma linguagem de marcação, que permite a manipulação do dado (ou dados) com facilidade. No `PHP`, o método [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) permite que você leia um `XML`, extraia os dados e faça com eles o que você quiser. Pra fazer um arquivo `.php` conversar com outro, você poderia usar o [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (o qual está me dando uma surra esta semana). Existe também o interminável [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), que permite consumir serviços assincronamente. Eu, particularmente, prefiro usar o formato `JSON` para as respostas, porquê a maioria das aplicações que consomem os meus serviços são escritas com o `AngularJS`.

Existem algumas padronizações para serviços, no sentido de como as perguntas e respostas devem ser feitas e construídas. Na [wiki sobre webservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#Web_services_that_use_markup_languages), você pode encontrar uma série de tipos de serviços que se baseiam em linguagens de marcação.

Você pode também se deparar com o termo RESTful APIs, que são basicamente serviços que se baseiam na [arquitetura REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Os serviços que eu construo são sempre baseados nesse modelo. Existe também [essa excelente história](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284) que explica como a referida arquitetura funciona.

Para a cereja do bolo, e a efeitos de curiosidade, o WordPress está implantando uma API RESTful de nome [WP API](http://wp-api.org/), que vai basicamente permitir tornar qualquer instância do WP em um webservice. Uma mãozona na roda, na minha opinião. =)

Answer (score 7):

**Exemplo prático**

Imagina a seguinte situação. Uma empresa tem um ERP cheio de rotinas e regras complexas. Agora imagina a seguinte situação. Essa empresa viu a necessidade de integra-lo com um sistema terceiro. Nesse sistema terceiro é especialista em gerenciar fluxos de trabalho. Um desses é o de compra de canetas. Porém, ao final, de nada adianta ele aprovar se não poder gerar essa compra no ERP.

**O Webservice**

Pois bem, aqui que entra o tal WebService. Esse cara prove uma ponte de comunicação entre sistemas. Nesse contexto da empresa, o ERP irá possuir um provedor de serviços. Esse provedor possuir um arquivo com todas as definições dos métodos de cada serviço. Por exemplo, um serviço de compra pode ter os métodos consultarCompraPorVendedor, gerarCompra, exluirCompra entre outros. Para esse arquivo se dá o nome de wsdl.

**Vantagens**

A grande vantagem de utilizar tal forma de integração (que não é a única) é a garantia que toda informação que saía e entre no ERP passe antes por todas as regras de negócio, sem falar na segurança de informação. Já que geralmente os métodos recebem alguma forma de autenticação como usuário/senha ou token. Além disso, caso o ERP evolua, o sistema terceiro não necessariamente precisará ser ajustado.

**Como funciona?**

A troca de dados entre sistemas basicamente funciona utilizando os protocolo Http e a XML/Json. Aonde no momento do envio algo chamado envelope SOAP é montado e após é enviado para o destinatário. Esse envelope possui no seu header alguns dados, como por exemplo, o endereçamento (ip/host, porta) do destinatário. Já no body do envelope vão os dados da requisição. No exemplo mencionado seria os dados da compra da caneta.

**O que mais?**

Além de tudo, o webservice também é conhecido como uma forma de integração multi-linguagem ou multiplataforma. Já que você pode ter, por exemplo, uma aplicação feita em java e outra feita em C# ambas as pontas podem se comunicar sem problemas utilizando a tecnologia dos WS.