# Qual a diferença entre Web Service e Application Service?

Tags: web-service, application-service

Pesquisando sobre o Web Service, questionei em um tópico sobre o tema, conforme link abaixo:

Pergunta: [O que é um Web Service?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90315/o-que-%C3%A9-um-web-service)

Porém, foi levantado uma questão sobre a distinção de Web Service e Application Service. Realizei uma rápida pesquisa sobre tal, mas não ficou muito clara. Segue abaixo as fontes:

Fonte Application Service: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Service_Provider

Fonte Web Service: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Afinal, quais são as diferenças entre ambas?

Comment: Só para deixar claro, eu usei o termo *application service* de uma forma geral, mas indicar e ali não tinha a definição do que realmente era *web service*, não quis usar isto como um termo formal. E o *link* usado acima é outra coisa.

Comment: Achei um FORUM dizendo a respeito. Click no link http://www.guj.com.br/java/104780-diferenca-web-server-web-container-e-application-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta pergunta até agora sem resposta demonstra que a diferença entre *"Application Service"* e *"Web Service"* não pode ser descrita do jeito certo; e nem do jeito errado.

*"Application Service"* sequer tem uma definição razoavelmente estabelecida, senão o google nos diria. Na verdade eu mesmo nunca usei esse termo.

Mas eu creio ter algo a contribuir, então segue:

## Um pouco de história

O termo **Web Service** tornou-se popular com o advento do **Microsoft .Net Framework**, lá no começo dos anos 2000.

Uma das grandes novidades da "revolucionária" plataforma da Microsoft eram os tais dos *Web Services* - um padrão de troca de mensagens para integração de sistemas de diferentes fornecedores, desenvolvidos com diferentes tecnologias.

Como definido pela Microsoft e documentado pelo **W3C**, **Web Services** usam o padrão **SOAP** de comunicação. Este protocolo foi desenvolvido por conta da **Microsoft** enquanto ela preparava o **.Net Framework** e depois foi submetido para padronização.

Então o .Net Framework e o Visual Studio vieram recheados de recursos para facilitar o desenvolvimento e consumo dos tais Web Services, usando o novo protocolo SOAP. Depois as demais plataformas tiveram que correr atrás para suportarem este padrão.

Já que **SOAP** é baseado em **XML**, de acordo com o W3C, Web Services recebem e devolvem código **XML** serializado, formatado de acordo com determinados padrões.

De acordo com esta definição histórica, portanto:

> **Web Services** é um padrão de troca de mensagens usando o protocolo **SOAP** e especialmente designado para integrar sistemas de **diferentes fornecedores**, desenvolvidos com **diferentes tecnologias**.

## Com o passar do tempo...

SOAP e seu comparsa XML se mostraram pesados demais, complicados demais.

Além disso, as corporações precisavam integrar não apenas softwares de diferentes fornecedores feitos em diferentes tecnologias, mas elas precisavam também separar e integrar com alta performance as camadas dos seus próprios sistemas a fim de obter escalabilidade.

Eventualmente os mesmos serviços consumidos por diferentes camadas de um mesmo sistema precisavam estar disponíveis também para consumo externo.

Daí começou a surgir "Web Service" usando JSON em vez de XML, ou usando comunicação binária proprietária em vez de serializar XML e JSON, ou usando HTTP puro e uma interface RESTfull, etc.

## Então por que as respostas da pergunta sobre Web Service não estariam de todo corretas?

Como eu já disse, não creiam que estejam incorretas. Web Services nasceram com uma definição específica, mas talvez por falta de nome melhor ou para reutilizar um nome já bastante difundido, nós fazemos serviços de integração pela internet sem usar SOAP e chamamos de Web Service.

## O que poderia ser o tal do *Application Service*?

Poderia ser uma fachada de serviços remotos de um sistema, para ser consumido pela camada de aplicação ou apresentação deste mesmo sistema.

O que distinguiria *Application Service* de *Web Service* seria o fato de que o primeiro preocupa-se principalmente com integração das camadas do mesmo sistema, sem interesse particular em usar um padrão de mercado para a troca de mensagens nem interesse particular em usar esta fachada de serviços para integrações externas.

Então ao contrário de um Web Service SOAP, o *Application Service* não precisaria ser auto-documentado nem utilizar protocolos padrão e nem seguir um padrão rígido de formato de mensagens.

Estas são minhas idéias sobre o que poderia diferenciar Web Service de uma coisa menos abrangente, que seria o tal do *Application Service*.

Talvez quem primeiro que trouxe o termo à luz naquela pergunta possa esclarecer melhor.

A função que esta resposta pretende cumprir é principalmente esclarecer a popularidade do termo "Web Service", deixando uma base para a discussão sobre o que poderia ou não ser chamado de Web Service e por quê.