# Como funciona o fluxo de um Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service

Preciso desenvolver um *web service*, e pelo que a sua principal ideia é a comunicação cliente-servidor.

Mas não entendo como isso seria feito usando a arquitetura MVC e usando a linguagem C#, será que tem a necessidade de um servidor local com o Apache?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é um Web Service?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90315/o-que-%c3%a9-um-web-service)

Comment: Para tentar lhe ajudar essas são suas chaves de pesquisa: [asp.net mvc web api](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=asp.net+mvc+web+api)

Answer (score 0):

> Como funciona o fluxo de um Web Service?

O princípio de funcionamento pode muito bem ser respondido [por essa excelente pergunta e suas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90315/o-que-%C3%A9-um-web-service), mais alguns complementos.

[Há vários protocolos que implementam um Web Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols). Os mais famosos deles são [SOAP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) e [REST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Se falamos de C#, estamos falando do padrão de projeto [ASP.NET Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.90).aspx) para SOAP e [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) para REST.

> Preciso desenvolver um web service, e pelo que a sua principal ideia é a comunicação cliente, servidor.

Não exatamente. A ideia principal está em fazer duas aplicações, não importando em quais plataformas são desenvolvidas, a conversarem. Uma pode ser cliente da outra e vice-versa.

> Mas não entendo como isso seria feito usando a arquitetura MVC e usando a linguagem C#, será que tem a necessidade de um servidor local com o Apache?

A arquitetura MVC não serve para construir *Web Services*. A arquitetura MVC serve para construir **aplicações**. A diferença básica entre eles é a entidade que interage com cada um. Na aplicação, será um usuário (normalmente um humano). No serviço, será uma aplicação ou outro serviço.

Normalmente, o servidor usado para aplicações e serviços web é o [IIS - Internet Information Services](http://www.iis.net/), ou Serviços de Informações da Internet. Após o lançamento do ASP.NET Core, há também a opção de outros servidores, como o [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer).

Ainda, se você realmente quer executar código .NET no Apache (o que é pouco recomendado, a não ser por alguma necessidade específica que você tenha), pode usar a biblioteca [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/).

Answer (score -3):

O que você está procurando é como criar um Serviço REST, ou seja, uma API.

Se você deseja usar C# para criar sua API, então siga os seguintes passos:

- Baixe o [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409): A melhor IDE do mercado, em sua versão gratuita.
- Enquanto faz o download do VS, leia este [Guia de Projeto API HTTP](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/http-api-design) e conheça mais sobre o assunto.
- Com o Visual Studio Community já instalado, leia este artigo para [construir seu primeiro serviço REST](http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/07/asp-net-web-api-meu-primeiro-servico-rest/) e crie seu primeiro API com C# e MVC.

Acredito ser um bom caminho das pedras para começar e criar seu *web service*.