# Qual a diferença entre WCF e um Web Services?

Tags: .net, web-service, wcf

Sempre trabalhei com Web Services, mas ultimamente tenho visto muito se fala sobre o WCF, dai veio minha duvida.

Qual a diferença entre WCF e um Web Services?

Existe alguma melhoria entre um e outro ou algo que seja melhor de usar entre eles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Web Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/101) é um conceito geral e WCF é uma tecnologia específica da Microsoft (.NET), então só por isso já é muito diferente.

Web Services costumam usar [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/101) como mecanismo básico. Há algumas regrinhas, mas é bem liberal como o dado pode ser trafegado. Web service nada tem a ver com XML. Pode ser usado em qualquer tecnologia web padrão. Web Service não é SOAP, ele pode trabalhar como SOAP.

WCF pode se comunicar de diversas formas, ela é uma tecnologia que tenta, na medida do possível, abstrair os diversos mecanismos de comunicação existentes, e um deles pode ser um *web service*. É um *framework extenso que tenta ser um SOA (*Service Oriented Architecture*). O legal dele é que você pode mudar o *binding* de comunicação sem mudar "nada" no código.

Alguns mecanismos são TCP, UDP, Named Pipes, Peer To Peer, MSQM, e é claro HTTP, entre outros, é possível até plugar novos. Ele não é só uma abstração na comunicação, ele tenta criar um padrão de troca de mensagens, como o *web service* o faz também.

WCF foi muito falado há 10 anos atrás, mas não hoje, está quase em desuso. É uma tecnologia pesada, difícil de aprender, usar e possui problemas de *design*. A ideia é boa, mas foi pessimamente implementado e algumas situações são específicas demais para aproveitar essa abstração. Tem espaço para seu uso, mas é mais limitado do que se pensava. Foi criado nos últimos dias da megalomania em desenvolvimento de software onde se acreditava que o computadores evoluiriam indefinidamente e abstrações sempre seriam vencedoras. Muito do que se lê dele é baseado em premissas que não se comprovaram ou que só fazia sentido 10 anos atrás.

Web Service é universal, WCF não, precisa ter aplicações preparadas para ela. Na verdade o mesmo ocorre com *web services*, mas por ser um padrão universal, tem interoperabilidade melhor.

Algumas pessoas gostam mais do [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net/), mas mesmo ele pode ser pesado e difícil demais além de não ser tão universal.

WCF essencialmente está abandonado (ainda suportado) e deve procurar outra tecnologia. A sugestão é usar [gRPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só por curiosidade: se eu precisar fazer em .NET uma "chamada de método remota" (RMI em Java), como faço? É com WCF mesmo?

Comment: Então o Web Services ainda é melhor para ser usar que o 
WCF?

Comment: Dei uma melhorada.

Comment: Legal. O muito se falar, foi em algumas empresas que fiz entrevista ultimamente e vagas de empregos que exigiam conhecimento em WCF.

Comment: Quem adota WCF casa com ele, por isso que eu falao pras pessoas não adotarem modinhas, tem que esperar amadurecer, ver se é aquilo tudo mesmo. https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/comments/6imnzj/%C3%A9_rid%C3%ADculo_como_as_modas_digitais_se_tornam_um/?ref=share&ref_source=link