# Equivalência de RMI (Java) em C#

Tags: java, c#, rmi

Qual é a equivalência de RMI (Remote Method Invocation - Java) em C#?

Comment: Equivalente mesmo não acho que tem. Existe o [Remoting framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx), mas que não deve ser usado mais. Não sei se o RMI ainda é usado. Hoje a recomendação oficial é usar o [WCF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215593/101), mas mesmo ele eu não recomendaria. Acho que tem soluções mais simples, leves.

Comment: Fiz a pergunta pois vi uma resposta sua não recomendando o uso do WCF, mas acredito que "na falta de tu, vai tu mesmo" né? @bigown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não conheço muito sobre o RMI e não sei até que ponto não estão usando o [Jini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini) no lugar dele.

Então eu diria que o [.NET Remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) seria o substituto direto. Porém a recomendação oficial é usar o [WCF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/index?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Mas muita gente não o usa também por ser algo pesado e difícil de aprender e usar e ter problemas de arquitetura. Tenho minhas dúvidas se não ocorre o mesmo como as tecnologias Java. O fato é que achavam que era fácil fazer um *framework*  que cuidava de tudo isso com uma boa abstração e flexibilidade, mas isso nunca deu muito certo.

Então se deseja usar mesmo tecnologia da Microsoft é o WCF o equivalente, se puder usar tecnologias de terceiros aí a gama é grande, tem gente usando o [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net/). Mas o pessoa tem adotado outras formas que não dependem desses grandes *frameworks*.

Na verdade o WCF está sendo aposentado, procure por tecnologias novas. Em parte recomenda-se o [gRPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).