# Como sites e aplicações web são convertidos em aplicativos mobile?

Tags: android, ios, aplicação-web, mobile

Muitos sites e aplicações web como o YouTube, redes sociais, e-commerces e sites de notícias tem suas versões em aplicativos móveis, e seus dados estão "Sincronizados" (por exemplo, quando coloco um vídeo no site do YouTube o vídeo também estará disponível no aplicativo).

A questão é: como é feito o aplicativo móvel de um site/aplicação web? É feito do zero, totalmente separado do site ou convertido de alguma forma? Se é feito de forma separada, é feito como um app híbrido ou nativo? E como essa "Sincronização de Dados e Atualizações" é feita (só uma ideia resumida de como isso é feito)?

Obrigado aos que reponderem!

Comment: Ou você implementa um aplicativo na plataforma que quer, ou usa um dos sites que convertem. Tem vários. Mas acho que eles apenas usam WebViews pra abrir o site dentro do app

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, empresas grandes desenvolvem apps nativos. O back-end do app é o mesmo do site, por isso que quando se posta um vídeo no site do youtube, ele também aparece no app. Pra isso que servem os [webservices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90315/o-que-%C3%A9-um-web-service/90340).
O Mark Zuckerberg, [falou que insistir demais em HTML ao invés de desenvolvimento nativo foi um grande erro](https://www.theverge.com/2012/9/11/3317230/mark-zuckerberg-betting-on-html5-for-mobile-was-a-mistake-hints-at).

Não existe essa conversão propriamente dita, o que algumas empresas fazem é rodar o site dentro de um web view em um app, a Globo faz isso, por exemplo. A google, por outro lado, desenvolveu um app nativo do youtube com os mesmos traços do site, o que da a impressão de que foi "gerado automaticamente", mas não foi.