# REST e HTTP são a mesma coisa?

Tags: rest, http, arquitetura-de-software

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre REST e HTTP. Desde um tempo, eu venho estudando esses dois assuntos e me parecem que são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Estou meio sem tempo de formular uma resposta, mas vou passar uma breve explicação, HTTP é um protocolo e o REST usa ele, então não são a mesma cosia. Qualquer página web que você acessa vem por HTTP, mas não vem em REST - **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45787/3635

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## `REST` e `HTTP` são a mesma coisa?

Não, não são.

## `HTTP`

`HTTP` significa **H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol e é o caminho mais popular para  a transferência de dados entre computadores. Este protocolo é utilizado para conectar páginas de hipertexto no que chamamos de world-wide-web (WWW). No entanto, existem também outros protocolos de transferência de dados disponíveis, como o `FTP` e o `gopher`, ainda que sejam menos populares.

Na prática funciona assim: quando você digita um endereço no navegador, ele precisa enviar alguma coisa para algum lugar dizendo que você quer ler alguma coisa. Imagine que você digitou o endereço do Google. Seu navegador prepara uma carta, isso mesmo, literalmente uma carta para o servidor onde fica o site do Google. Nessa carta é onde existe a requisição com os métodos `HTTP`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## `REST`

**RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer, ou `REST`, é um conjuto de regras que garantem um sistema escalavel, facilmente extensível e tolerante a falhas. A world-wide-web é um exemplo desse tipo de sistema (e o maior exemplo possivel). `REST` por si só, não é uma nova invenção, mas é a documentação para sistemas como a the world-wide-web.

Uma coisa que confunde muito as pessoas, é que `REST` e `HTTP` são bastante atrelados. E não por acaso, a world-wide-web roda sobre o protocolo `HTTP`, e uma API RESTful também é baseada nesse mesmo protocolo. Mas, não há nada nas regras do `REST` que diga que o uso do protocolo `HTTP` é estritamente obrigatório. É perfeitamente aceitável utilizar outro protocolo como o `SNMP`, `SMTP` ou outros, e sua API ainda sim poderá ser uma RESTful API.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Conclusão

Em prática, a maioria - se não todos - API's RESTful utilizam o `HTTP` como seu protocolo de comunicação. Já que infraestrutura, servers e bibliotecas de client estão altamente disponíveis para esse protocolo do comunicação. O `REST` se baseia em um estilo arquitetural que consiste de um conjunto coordenado de restrições arquiteturais aplicadas a componentes, conectores e elementos de dados dentro de um sistema de hipermídia distribuído. O `HTTP` é o principal protocolo para a transferência de dados nesse estilo arquitetural.

Comment: Muito bem explicado +1..

Answer (score 3):

**REST é um protocolo de comunicação, baseado no protocolo de hipermídia HTTP**. Porém ele não impõe restrições ao formato da mensagem, apenas no comportamento dos componentes envolvidos.

A maior vantagem do protocolo REST é sua flexibilidade. O desenvolvedor pode optar pelo formato mais adequado para as mensagens do sistema de acordo com sua necessidade específica. Os formais mais comuns são Json, XML e texto puro, mas em teoria qualquer formato pode ser usado.

Isso nos leva a outra vantagem: quase sempre Web Services que usam REST são mais "leves" e, portanto, mais rápidos.

O problema com o REST pode surgir justamente por causa de suas vantagens. Como a definição do corpo de dados fica totalmente a cargo do desenvolvedor, os problemas de interoperabilidade são mais comuns.

> Fonte: [Diferenças de tipos de Web Service: SOAP, REST, XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11183/diferen%C3%A7as-de-tipos-de-web-service-soap-rest-xml)