# REST - Http x Json

Tags: json, web-service, xml, rest, soap

Fiz algumas pesquisas e tenho alguma dúvidas sobre REST:

- Http é Rest?
- JSON e XML são apenas o formato de retorno de uma operação Rest?
- REST x Web Services: são a mesmas coisas?
- SOAP seria o oposto de HTTP?

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta responde o primeiro item: [O que é REST e RESTful?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/91)

Comment: Comentário muito útil @rray.

Comment: Mas ainda fiquei na dúvida, Http é Rest? E as demais questões, alguém?

Comment: Essa não bate na trave igual a primeira => [REST e HTTP são a mesma coisa?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95836/91)

Comment: Se eu tenho um arquivo JSP que retorna um JSON, ele não necesseriamente é um REST?

Answer (score 9):

[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read):

- Não
- Não
- Não
- Não

Versão não tão curta:

- > Http é Rest?

*HTTP* é um protocolo de aplicações que especifica o comportamento e tráfego de hipertexto; *REST* é um estilo arquitetural cujo foco são elementos de dados. REST pode ser implementado sobre HTTP, porém HTTP pode ser utilizado para implementar várias outras arquiteturas - SOAP, por exemplo.

- > JSON e XML são apenas o formato de retorno de uma operação Rest?

Enquanto que a grande maioria das implementações atuais de REST utilizam JSON e XML como formatos de troca de dados com consumidores, eles não são apenas utilizados em estruturas REST. Qualquer processo que necessite de serialização de dados (arquivamento em disco ou autenticação, por exemplo) pode se beneficiar destes dois formatos.

- > REST x Web Services: são a mesmas coisas?

Um WebService pode ser implementado contendo endpoints REST, porém não exclusivamente. Como mencionado anteriormente, endpoints SOAP (entre outros) são práticas válidas.

- > SOAP seria o oposto de HTTP?

Não. Sendo SOAP um formato baseado em XML, a grande maioria das implementações ocorrem sobre HTTP.

Comment: Se eu tenho um arquivo JSP que retorna um JSON, ele não necesseriamente é um REST?

Comment: @stringNome um alerta em relação a edição: os itens que você removeu na edição são relevantes, e podem até alterar a intenção do autor, então foi rejeitada. Quando for editar, procure fazer edições que deixem mais clara do conteúdo, sem que afete  a intenção do autor naquela resposta/pergunta.

Comment: @LuizaCH não necessariamente - um resultado JSON não implica em uma API REST. Várias APIs do Google expõem dados em JSON, porém não representam um objeto de dados nem implementam REST. Exemplo: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

Comment: Como posso chamar um arquivo de JSP que retorna dados via JSON?

Comment: @LuizaCH isso irá depender das tecnologias que você está utilizando na sua solução, e talvez fuja um pouco do tópico desta pergunta. Se desejar, crie uma nova pergunta e mostre-nos até onde você já chegou.