# Framework REST para API PHP

Tags: php

Quero desenvolver uma API para que alguns sites possam coletar dados da minha base de dados. Pesquisando eu vi que existem muitos Frameworks para esta finalidade. A idéia é que a API permita login e execute os métodos GET, PUT, DELETE, POST.. Qual o melhor Framework para inciante? Levando em consideração desempenho, segurança..

Comment: Neste caso o melhor será aquele que você sabe utilizar. Se não sabe nenhum, veja aquele que mais lhe agrade e estude-o. Sem ter métricas definidas, definir o melhor será meramente questão de opinião pessoal e, por este motivo, votei para fechar a pergunta como baseada em opinião.

Comment: Para criar API rest em PHP aconselho usar o LUMEN. Ela é bem simple e a documentação é muito boa
https://lumen.laravel.com/

Comment: Essa é a idéia da pergunta. Documentação é importante, não adianta me indicarem um Framework que não encontro documentação.. VAleu!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Entendendo** o básico do que é REST e HTTP quase qualquer framework de **controle de rotas** pode criar facilmente uma aplicação REST, recomendo que leia:

- [O que é REST e RESTful?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/3635)
- [Quais as principais diferenças entre SOAP, REST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/3635)
- [O que é um Web Service?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/3635)
- [REST e HTTP são a mesma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95836/3635)

Recomendo que entenda o básico do HTTP também, pois isto é o básico para se entender REST:

- [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/3635)

Não dá para indicar o melhor framework, mas para PHP como disse, quase qualquer framework que trabalhe com rotas facilmente servirá para REST, lista de frameworks e micro-frameworks:

- https://www.slimframework.com
- https://www.waveframework.com
- https://lumen.laravel.com
- http://silex.sensiolabs.org
- https://limonade-php.github.io
- http://flightphp.com

Se sua aplicação atual for Laravel e você necessitar de aproveitar as regras ou Models existentes no seu projeto em Laravel, você pode usar o [Resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers), por exemplo:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

O `PhotoController` é a sua classe e `photos` é o "prefixo" da rota, que poderá ser acessado assim:

| Verbo | URI | Método | Nome da rota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `GET` | `/photos` | `index` | `photos.index` |
| `GET` | `/photos/create` | `create` | `photos.create` |
| `POST` | `/photos` | `store` | `photos.store` |
| `GET` | `/photos/{photo}` | `show` | `photos.show` |
| `GET` | `/photos/{photo}/edit` | `edit` | `photos.edit` |
| `PUT/PATCH` | `/photos/{photo}` | `update` | `photos.update` |
| `DELETE` | `/photos/{photo}` | `destroy` | `photos.destroy` |

Comment: Entender [o protocolo HTTP e as requisições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174116/como-o-protocolo-http-processa-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es) também vai gerar um bom ganho ;D

Comment: @gato Perfeito!

Comment: Ótimo galera!!!