# Erro ao utilizar POST em API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Estou aprendendo a construir uma API utilizando Laravel 5.4.*.

No `Api.php`:

```
$this->get('products', 'API\ProductController@index', ['except' => [
    'create', 'edit'
]]);
```

No `Product.php`:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];
}
```

No `ProductController.php`:

```
private $product;

public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function index()
{
    $products = $this->product->all();

    return response()->json(['data' => $products]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'result' => $this->product->create($request->all())
    ]);
}
```

Revisei meu código e não consegui encontrar erros.

Quando utilizo GET retorna os produtos cadastrados, porém quando utilizo o POST recebo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está correto e o erro também :)

```
$this->get('products'
```

Essa rota especifica que somente requisições atráves do método get será processadas do contrario será retornando o código http 405 método não permitido. Conceitualmente pesquisa são feitas atráves do método get, para criar/adicionar novos recursos utiliza-se o post.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/91)

[O que é REST e RESTful?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/91)

[REST e HTTP são a mesma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95836/91)

[Rest api tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)

[Artigo original sobre rest](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)

[API design - MS Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design)

Comment: Criei um `$this->post('products', 'API\ProductController@store', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);` e funcionou, vlw mesmo!

Comment: @Mateus coloquei uns link complementares, a ideia do rest é diferente de uma aplicação web normal.

Comment: Achei uma alternativa para o laravel >= 5.3 que é utilizar `$this->resource('products', 'API\ProductController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);` e ele já seleciona o método adequado