# Dúvida com webservice método put e delete. Como implementar em java?

Tags: java, web-service, rest

O que tenho que implementar para disponibilizar um Webservice que suporte PUT ou DELETE.

Eu sou novata nesse mundo webservice se vocês pudessem me ajudar me enviando pelo menos um link de onde eu posso ler algo sobre.

Comment: O que já tem tentado? Posta seu código por favor. Pode explicar porque tem que ser PUT e DELETE?

Comment: Só um momento que eu vou testar, to tentando melhorar aqui rapidinho, espera aí.

Comment: Se não conhece nada sobre, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11183/diferen%C3%A7as-de-tipos-de-web-service-soap-rest-xml) pode ser um bom caminha pra começar.

Comment: não entendi, como assim te expulsando?rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns frameworks que facilitam no desenvolvimento de webservices em java, um dos mais populares é o [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Exemplo de `PUT` e `DELETE` com `Spring`:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {  
        //busca um usuário por id(Parametro passado pro método updateUser)      
        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);  
        if (currentUser==null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        currentUser.setName(user.getName());
        currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
        currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());
        //Faz o update do usuário no banco
        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        //Retorna o usuário junto com código 200
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        //Busca um usuário por id(passado por parâmetro)
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        //Deleta o usuário
        userService.deleteUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

O `Spring` é um framework bastante utilizado e bem prático. Uma sugestão seria considerar a possibilidade de utilizar [Vraptor](http://www.vraptor.org/pt/) onde os `Controllers` são escritos de maneira mais limpa, ex:

```
@Controller
public class ClienteController {

    @Post("/cliente")
    public void adiciona(Cliente cliente) {...}

    @Path("/")
    public List<Cliente> lista() {
        return ...
    }

    @Get("/cliente")
    public Cliente visualiza(Cliente cliente) {
        return ...
    }
    @Get("/cliente/{codigo}")
    public Cliente listarPorCodigo(Long codigo) {
        return ...
    }

    @Delete("/cliente")
    public void remove(Cliente cliente) { ... }

    @Put("/cliente")
    public void atualiza(Cliente cliente) { ... }
}
```

Materiais:

[CRUD com Spring](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-restful-web-services-crud-example-resttemplate/)

[REST com Vraptor](http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/controllers-rest/)