# Troca de XML entre service e cliente

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou estudando WCF e todo o material inicial que encontro tudo se resume a coisas muito básicas, expondo métodos que recebem alguns parâmetros e devolvem algum valor.

Preciso criar um web service que será a interface entre o banco de dados e aplicações externas. As aplicações externas poderão fazer inserções, exclusões e alterações em registros.

Penso que isso deve ser feito via troca de arquivos XML, ou seja, para a aplicação externa inserir um registro de um novo cliente por exemplo, ela deverá enviar ao Web Service um XML com todos os dados necessários para o cadastro do referido cliente.

Como eu implemento isso?

Comment: Eu não consegui entender a sua pergunta.

Comment: Mas se está interessado em criar webservices que trabalham com você pode procurar por topicos como SOAP,WSDL e REST.

Comment: Eu só encontro exemplos tolos como por exemplo um web servisse que expõe um método chamado `soma` que recebe dois inteiros e devolve o resultado.
Assim uma aplicação que consome o serviço chama o método, passa dos dois inteiros e recebe o resultado da soma.
Como seria por exemplo o método responsável por fazer a inserção de um cliente, cujo o cadastro contem 30 campos? Criar um método com 30 parâmetros um para cada campo?

Comment: Só pra esclarecer. Este procedimento é feito com envio e recebimento de XML por baixo dos panos. Essa simplificação, se eu não me engano, se chama RPC (Remote procedure call), parece que você está consumindo um método local, mas na verdade, é feita uma chamada pro seu webservice enviando estes dados e tecendo o resultado via XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta é mais curta é: você não implementa. O *framework* faz tudo isso por você.

Esse "simplificação", que faz parecer com que você esteja chamando métodos locais, se chama [RPC (remote procedure call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) - que, na minha opinião, é um dos pontos mais interessantes do WCF e ASMX.

Por "baixo dos panos" o que acontece é um envio e recebimento de XML's. Porém, tudo isso é extremamente regrado, com tipagem, e todas as outras vantagens de se fazer uma chamada local. Esta "regra" é definida por meio de um arquivo WSDL, todos os *webservices* desenvolvidos em WFC, por padrão terão este arquivo.

O WSDL também se encarrega de levar os tipos (classes) criados no *webservice* para aplicação cliente. Então, se existir uma classe **`Cliente`** no *webservice*, no momento que você criar a referência para o mesmo (isso geralmente é feito pelo Visual Studio) este tipo também passa a existir no projeto cliente.

A partir daí é só mandar o objeto para o método remoto que o *framework* fará todo o "trabalho sujo" por você. Obviamente que você pode configurar tudo, mudar algumas coisas, até mesmo escolher o formato dos dados (JSON, XML, etc.).

---

WCF é um framework para construção de aplicações orientadas a serviços (SOA), você pode ler algumas coisas bem interessantes em [Diferenças de tipos de Web Service: SOAP, REST, XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/18246).

Comment: Então o método exposto pode receber um objeto `Cliente` normalmente? Nesse caso o programa externo também deve ter uma classe do tipo cliente e passar esse objeto "preenchido" para o método do Web Server.
Seria isso?

Comment: As demais dúvidas estou sanando com  essa sequência de [vídeos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYW01fOF5WFtnzdt78sqkUg/videos) sobre WCF do Israel Aece.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Isso mesmo. Perceba que geralmente o próprio Visual Studio vai criar as classes responsáveis pelo contrato no seu projeto cliente.