# Qual a diferença entre GraphQL e REST?

Tags: api, rest, back-end, graphql

O pessoal tem comentado bastante sobre o uso de GraphQL e com isso, alguns comentários de que irá substituir essa ascensão que temos de API's REST.

- Qual a diferença entre os dois (GraphQL e REST)?
- E, em que cenário é interessante eu optar por GraphQL e/ou REST?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O GraphQL é uma linguagem de busca, até ai o REST também faz.

A diferença é que com GraphQL você busca exatamente o que você quer (um *front-end* sabe exatamente como isso funciona).

Por exemplo, eu fiz uma API em Graphql envolvendo a [API](https://www.instagram.com/greyapplebr/?__a=1) do meu Instagram.

Se você clicar no link, você vai reparar que aparece um JSON enorme.

Com REST você pega todos esses dados, com GraphQL você pega somente o que é necessário para você. Isso reduz a carga de dados enviados do servidor para o navegador.

[image: JSON]

Em resumo, acredito que seja essa a vantagem do GraphQL.

Várias empresas estão migrando de REST para GraphQL, dá uma olhada nessa [lista](http://graphql.org/users/).

Caso você queira começar, esse [tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/) é excelente.

Também vale a pena ver esse [*post*](https://open.nytimes.com/react-relay-and-graphql-under-the-hood-of-the-times-website-redesign-22fb62ea9764) do *New York Times* falando a migração que eles fizeram.

Comment: Resposta clara e pontual. Muito obrigado Alessander. De forma resumida você explanou a diferença entre as duas abordagens e exemplificou com links.

Seguirei aquele tutorial que você recomendou. Obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha sido bem claro. Eu segui esse tutorial e aprendi bastante ;)

Comment: Acrescentando um post que encontrei recentemente: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/graphql-vs-rest-5d425123e34b

Answer (score 12):

O GraphQL foi criado para abordar, por exemplo, os seguintes problemas com o REST:

(1) a URL fica complicada com relações complexas e de muito nesting

(2) o problema de "overfetching," quando você obtém mais dados do que precisa

(3) o problema de fazer muitos pedidos de HTTP para vários tipos de recursos (ou se você tem que fazer muitos pedidos para o mesmo recurso, um por um)

No REST, tem uma URL com um verbo de HTTP para cada operação CRUD. Por exemplo,

- para obter todos os produtos de um certo backend: `GET /produtos`;
- para obter o récorde de um produto: `GET /produtos/123456`, onde 123456 é o id do produto.
- e assim por diante

No GraphQL, só tem um único endpoint, normalmente `POST /graphql`. Todas as operações são realizadas por meio desse caminho. Para obter dados, você faz uma **query**. Para modificar os dados, você faz uma **mutation**. Para assinaturas, você faz uma **subscription**.

No REST, quando você faz pedido para obter dados de, por exemplo, um certo produto, o recorde JSON normalmente vem com tudo que tem disponível sobre aquele produto.

As vezes o seu frontend só precisa de uma ou duas propriedades, mas o objeto json vem com umas 30+. Isso se torna um problema, principalmente se você quer servir usuários de aplicativos móveis que não tem uma conexão muito boa. Essa foi uma das razões que a galera do Facebook criou o GraphQL.

Com o GraphQL, você pode pedir ao backend exatamente o que você precisa. Por exemplo, no caso do produto, se só precisamos do nome do produto, basta fazer uma query ao GraphQL assim:

```
query {
  produto(id: "123456") {
    nome
  }
}
```

O exemplo acima é bem simples. Ele economiza a bandwidth como só retorna uma propriedade em formato json pro usuário.

Outro exemplo mais complexo é o seguinte. No meu trabalho já me deparei muito com situações onde um pedido HTTP pra uma API não me dá todas as informações necessárias pro frontend. Por isso, sempre tenho que fazer vários outros pedidos (incluindo de várias outras APIs) só pra poder obter e injetar essas informações no objeto inicial.

Se uma `Companhia` tem vários `Produtos`; e cada produto têm vários `Modelos`, fazendo `GET /companhias/4321/produtos/123` em REST me daria informações sobre o produto 123, mas talvez não incluiria todas as informações sobre a companhia. Digo isso se usar um backend MVC que gera rotas e ações REST automaticamente. As vezes fazendo `GET /companhias/4321` lhe dá acesso aos produtos, mas cada produto nāo inclui informaçāo sobre os modelos (só incluiria o `modeloId` de cada).

Você já vê que o negócio acima fica complicado e mais difícil de entender rapidamente. E você tem que fazer várias personalizações no backend pra poder obter todos os dados desejados. Ou você teria que fazer vários pedidos HTTP e fazer processamento de dados no frontend.

Com o GraphQL, embora que você tenha que configurar tudo no backend, do frontend você só faz o seguinte:

```
query {
  companhia(id: "4321") {
    nome
    dataDeFundacao
    produto(id: "123") {
      id
      nome
      modelos {
        id
        nome
        dataDeLancamento
        preco
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Com a query acima, você obteria informações específicas sobre a companhia 4321, além das informações específicas do produto 123, além de todos os modelos incluindo `id`, `nome`, `dataDeLancamento`, e `preco`. E tudo isso viria de um só pedido de HTTP, do único endpoint `/graphql`. É importante notar que as informações não precisam vir da mesma API. Você pode ter várias APIs em vários locais e usar o GraphQL para combinar tudo em uma só resposta.

Para concluir, eu recomendaria usar o GraphQL se você tiver constante problemas como os mencionados anteriormente.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar as respostas acima irei citar um projeto que trabalhei recentemente e implementei graphql.

Eu estava trabalhando em um projeto que consumia uma API REST de CMS, então eu pagava as categorias, subcategorias, produtos e ofertas via esta API e mandava pro front-end consumir, o problema surgiu quando os cadastros no CMS cresceram, ae o json final que estava sendo enviado para o front-end estava com um tamanho próximo dos 4mb, o q é muita coisa, ae pra resolver isso eu tinha duas opções:

1 - Filtrar os dados no servidor, o que iria necessitar de muito código e tratamentos especificos, daria bastante trabalho.

2 - Criar um servidor graphql e consumir esta API REST atraves do graphql.

Eu escolhi a opção 2 e isso fez o tamanho do json de resposta cair de quase 4mb para 50kb em alguns casos, pq passei a solicitar somente o necessário para o servidor, e isso juntamente com algumas técnicas de cache solucionou meu problema.

Então este é o grande beneficio do GraphQL, permitir ao front-end que consuma somente o necessário, e não necessariamente precisa ser um substituto ao REST, pois em alguns casos como sistemas legados você não poderá simplesmente parar de usar a API REST, então o que você pode fazer é unir os dois onde fizer sentido e colher os mesmos beneficios.