# Qual seria o formato dos dados trafegados por um web service SOAP?

Tags: web-service, soap

Em web services que usam a arquitetura REST, o formato dos dados que é trafegado pela rede é XML ou JSON, em alguns casos podem ser ambos. No entanto, eu não sei qual é o formato dos dados que são trafegados em um web service SOAP.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber qual seria o formato dos dados trafegados pela rede através de um web service SOAP?

Comment: Alguma sugestão de melhoria na pergunta downvoter?

Comment: Segue uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11183/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-soap-rest-xml) com conteúdos interessantes a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Um web service `SOAP` trafega `XML`

Mais info aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

> A SOAP message MUST be encoded using XML

Ou seja, as mensagens `SOAP` trafegam sempre em `XML`

> A SOAP message is an ordinary XML document

Ou seja, sempre um documento XML.

Aqui, o esqueleto básico de uma mensagem `SOAP` e seu formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Header>
     ...
  </soap:Header>

  <soap:Body>
     ... Aqui vai o corpo da mensagem em XML
    <soap:Fault>
       ...
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Só a referência que não é confiável. `w3schools` é considerada uma ótima piada, onde você tentava contar quantos erros existiam em uma página aleatória que você abria

Comment: Ah, também não é qualquer xml que pode ser trafegado. Dentro do xml, tem um formato específico

Comment: @hugocsl a parte mais relevante do link foi incluída na resposta *"A SOAP message MUST be encoded using XML"*

Comment: Apena fiz a Revisão, mas já removi, considerando a sua Edição da resposta.

Comment: A especificação do protocolo realmente fala que a mensagem deve ser no formato XML. Porém só para colocar lenha da fogueira: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAPjr  (Ok até dá para argumentar que SOAPjr não é SOAP). Já vi algumas coisas absurdas também, do tipo um corpo "XML" com um único campo CDATA e algum outro formato completamente louco (e.g., arquivo posicional) como conteúdo. Novamente dá para argumentar que isso é XML válido, mas...