# Diferença entre Webservice, API e RESTful

Tags: web-service, api, restful

Não estou conseguindo ver a diferença entre eles. Todos os três são serviços web que podem trabalhar com dados externamente, mas eu não consigo compreender a diferença. O RESTful trabalha com json, mas a API e webservice também podem. Eu imagino que a diferença deve ser minima, mesmo que eu ainda não tenha notado.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/101

Answer (score 0):

Uma API (Application Programming Interface) é o meio pelo qual terceiros podem escrever interfaces para se comunicar com outro código. Um WebService é um tipo de API, que quase sempre opera sobre HTTP (embora alguns, como o SOAP, possam usar protocolos alternativos, como o SMTP). A definição oficial do W3C menciona que os Web Services não usam necessariamente HTTP, mas isso não é comum. As APIs em geral podem usar qualquer meio de comunicação que desejarem.

Já REST, é um estilo de arquitetura de software, que basicamente explora a tecnologia e os protocolos existentes na Web. E o RESTful é normalmente usado para se referir a serviços da Web que implementam essa arquitetura.